# How do I get the document path using the Autodesk A360 API?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-bim360

When looking at the [API documentation](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/projects-project_id-items-item_id-GET/), it states it should be able to set a query parameter: includePathInProject. Using that, the relative path should be included in the response.

> includePathInProject
>
> Specify whether to return pathInProject attribute in response for BIM 360 Docs projects. pathInProject is the relative path of the item starting from project’s root folder.
>
> true: response will include pathInProject attribute for BIM 360 Docs projects.
>
> false (default): response will not include pathInProject attribute for BIM 360 Docs projects.

However, when I try this in Postman, I get this message:

```
{
"jsonapi": {
    "version": "1.0"
},
"errors": [
    {
        "id": "34a40e9d-2db2-4a32-ac9a-fc0642207266",
        "status": "400",
        "code": "FUNCTION_NOT_SUPPORTED",
        "detail": "A360 currently does not support query parameter includePathInProject."
    }
]
```

}

This is the request URL I'm using:

```
https://developer.api.autodesk.com/data/v1/projects/:project_id/items/:item_id?includePathInProject=true

project_id: a.Yna[...]zgx
item_id: urn:adsk.wipprod:dm.lineage:0P0E[...]l5A
```

Is there any other way or workaround to get the path of a document?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you're trying to use it for A360 projects, I see an `a.` prefix on your project id. This parameter applies to BIM 360 only.